# How to do a darker background image in css3 and stretch it?

Tags: html, css

Im doing the following in css:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url('../img/back.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
```

i want to stretch the image to 100% 100%, how should i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-size: 100% 100%;`.

Alternatively:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url('../img/back.jpg') no-repeat fixed center / 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 background-size:100% 100% // or cover
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you cannot stretch an image in background with CSS.
To start, you can use more accurate CCS:

```
body {
    background-image:  url('../img/back.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

But the picture will not stretch with this.
An other possibility than CSS, is to use a cell of a table with a picture, in a div that is set to background:

```
<div class=background>
    <table width=100%><TR><TR>
        <img src="../img/back.jpg" width=100%></TR>
    </TR></TR></table>
</div>
```

And in CSS, you have to create layers with different z-index:

```
div.background {
    z-index:  -1;
    position: fixed;
    left:     0px;
    top:      0px;
    float:    top;}
div.notbackground {
    z-index:  0;
    position: absolute;
    left:     0px;}
```

the rest of your page should be placed in the "notbackground" div to appear in higher layer, so the picture is really on background. z-index=0 is higher than z-index=-1 (you ca use any numbers). This way your picture will appear as a background.

It's possible that some advanced CSS do the trick but after a quick search on Google I still don't know.